# Rails save model separate from creating model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, user-controls

I have a `def show` that updates my User models each time they are viewed. The challenge is that I want to update specific attributes without updating everything. Currently I update `@user.year` and `@user.today_steps`

When I try to save with `@user.save` an error occurs.

```
p @user.errors.full_messages
```

returns `["Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)"]` but I'm not trying to update the password. How do I save and update some attributes without updating all of them? The reason this is a challenge is because my model needs to validate some attributes.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# attr email, name, points

before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
before_create :create_remember_token

attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :year, :today_steps

has_many :competitions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :attendees, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :competitions, :through => :attendees

  has_one :device

validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

has_secure_password
validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }

  serialize :year, Array
```

Comment: What does your `show` action look like?

Comment: The action code would be really helpful because it is not clear if the error occurs when you are updating the record or when you are saving it.

Comment: @Mhsmith21 – we can't help you unless you provide more detail.

Answer (score 2):

An optional parameter can be passed to the save method, this parameter allows you to bypass the validations and to save your object anyway. Do you want to bypass all validations and save your object ?

If yes :

```
@user.save(validate: false)
```

Note that the validations won't occur only for this operation. (I guess it's what you want)

Comment: This worked for one of the variables being changed (an int), but destroyed the .year Array (changed it from `[]` to `0`) any ideas why this is?

Comment: I don't think it is related to the validations. Can you check on if your database field is a string, maybe you have done a mistake and you put an integer there... That's the only thing I can think of. Check your db/schema.rb file and tell me what is the type of the year field of the user table.

Comment: @Oxynum I would not recommend you to skip your validations, this could turn into a problem later. Updating only the attributes you want is much safer

Comment: I don't like to skip the validations either but I think it is what he was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

use update_attributes

@user.update_attributes(:today_steps => "asdf", :year => "2012")

http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attributes